# Access relational data of many to many relationship with multiple database connection with different server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I'm working with multiple database connection on different servers. i.e, `host1` and `host2`. My default database connection is host2. My project have two tables. **`users` exists on host1** and **`tasks` exists on host2**.

There is a `many to many` relationship on both tables. Pivot table for this relationship is **`task_users` which exists on host2**.

My model files are here.

**User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $connection = 'host1';

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'task_users', 'user_id', 'task_id');
    }
}
```

**Task.php**

```
class Task extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'host2';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'task_users', 'task_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

With this model files, when I'm trying to get users of a task, I'm getting this error.

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database_hosted_on_host1_server.task_users' doesn't exist.

**Here is my Controller Code**

```
$task = Task::find($taskId);
dd($task->users->toArray());
```

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671664/solvedlaravel-how-to-set-connection-for-many-to-many-relationship) too. But it works only if both database are on same server.

I have also tried **Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models** from [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). But still getting error. I think I'm doing some mistake in pivot class.

Here is my code.

**Task.php**

```
class Task extend Model
{
    protected $connection = 'host2';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->using(TaskUser::class);
    }
}
```

**TaskUser.php**

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

```
class TaskUser extends Pivot
{
    protected $connection = 'host2';
    protected $table = 'task_users';
}
```

With this code, when I'm trying to get users of a task, I'm getting this error.

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database_hosted_on_host1_server.task_user' doesn't exist.

In both code, relational table is getting assigned with host1 connection (connection of related table i.e, users). But it exists in host2 connection. And also my default connection is host2.

I have almost spent too much time to resolve this. But didn't get any way. If anyone knows the answer, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I got the answer from [themsaid](https://github.com/themsaid) on github. He said that many to many relationships on different connections would work in 1 direction only but not the other. Here you can find [github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/20636).

Answer (score 1):

On your model, try defining 'connection.table' like this:

User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $table = 'host1.users';

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'task_users', 'user_id', 'task_id');
    }
}
```

Task.php

```
class Task extend Model
{
    protected $table = 'host2.tasks';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->using(TaskUser::class);
    }
}
```

And your pivot TaskUser.php

```
class TaskUser extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'host2.task_users';
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error if I make changes as per your answer. `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'host2.tasks' doesn't exist`

Comment: Did you test your database connections?

Comment: I have tested my database connection. Both are connected.