# Get relational data of many to many relationship with multiple database connection

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationship, eloquent

- Laravel Version: 5.5.
- PHP Version: ">=7.0.0",
- Database Driver & Version: MySQL

#### Description:

I'm working with multiple database connections that have different schema. `host1` and `host2`. My default database connection is host2. 
My project has two tables. users exist on host1 and tasks exists on host2.

There is a many to many relationships on both tables. Pivot table for this relationship is `task_users` which exist on host2.

My model files are here.

> User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

   protected $connection = 'host1';

   public function tasks()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'task_users', 'user_id', 'task_id');
   }
}
```

> Task.php

```
class Task extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'host2';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'task_users', 'task_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

#### Steps To Reproduce:

Here is what I'm trying to do

`$task = Task::find($taskId);
$task->users;`

With this model files, when I'm trying to get users of a task, I'm getting this error.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  the "task_user" relationship does not exist

But then if I do the inverse like this:

`$user = User::find($userId);
$user->task;`

everything goes fine.

I have almost spent too much time to resolve this. But didn't get anyway. I don't know either this is an issue in laravel, not supported or I'm doing in wrong way.

Comment: Since task_user is in host2, on defining the relationship on your task->belongsToMany users you need a way to specify which database

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142968/belongstomany-relationship-in-laravel-across-multiple-databases

Answer (score 0):

specify the connection

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'host2.task_users', 'task_id', 'user_id');
}
```