# Laravel polimorphic relation for multiple databases

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, relation

I am trying to make a polymorphic relationship between two database tables.

database1: SaleReport
database2: ThreadConnection

under SaleReport on database1

```
public function relates(){
    return $this->morphMany(ThreadConnection::class, 'relation');
}
```

on ThreadConnection at database2

```
public function relation(){
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

But when i try to get the relation like

```
$salereport = App\SaleReport::find(1);
$salereport->relates


Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: 
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database1.thread_connections'
doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `thread_connections` where 
`thread_connections`.`relation_id` = 484694 and 
`thread_connections`.`relation_id` is not null and 
`thread_connections`.`relation_type` = App/SaleReport)'
```

I have also tried to define the database connection into the ThreadConnection

$this->setConnection('database2')->morphTo();

But that doesn't worked either!

Any suggestion would be appriciate

Comment: Did you try to set  protected $connection = 'database2'; in ThreadConnection model?

Comment: I think it's already been answered here what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142968/belongstomany-relationship-in-laravel-across-multiple-databases

Comment: Hi @koalaok, Thanks yes I have done that added the protected $connection = 'db1/db2' in both the model belongs to the databasaes, and the table names protected $table = 'table_names' and that worked like a charm, it was really good that it's that easy to make a relation between two databases with polymorphic relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated previously in my comment,

Reading the Error:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database1.thread_connections'
```

Meaning Laravel is looking in database1 connection for model ThreadConnection (database1 should be the default connection, if model refers to another connection it should be set explicitly)

Adding in ThreadConnection:

```
 protected $connection = 'database2';
```

Will solve the issue.