# Eloquent Relationship Multiple Connection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a multi-connection application. Model `Department` is on a different connection from model `CutOff`.

I have a relationship in my `CutOff` that looks like this:

```php
public function department()
{
    $department = new Department();
    $database = $department->getConnection()->getDatabaseName();

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Department', 'department_id',    "$database.department.id");
}
```

So I try to call it like this from my view ...

```php
$cut_off->department->name;
```

I get this error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`id` = ? limit
>   1' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `departments` where
>   `departments`.`uni_main`.`department`.`id` = 2 limit 1) (View:
>   C:\wamp\www\university\resources\views\utme\dashboard\cut_off\index.blade.php)

Please how do I get around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [belongsToMany relationship in Laravel across multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142968/belongstomany-relationship-in-laravel-across-multiple-databases)

Comment: @HCK I tried it out and i get this error                        ** ErrorException (E_ERROR)
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'uni_utme.departments' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `departments` where `departments`.`uni_utme`.`departments` = 2 limit 1) **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `protected $connection = 'the_other_db';` on the Department model which matches what is configured in database.php

Then I can just use

```
public function department()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Department', 'department_id');
}
```