# Laravel BelongsToMany on different databases

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-connection, relationship

In my app (Laravel 9) users can belong to groups, and users can access resources "attached" to the group(s) they belong to.

However the resources are stored on a different database (we use two distinct RDS instances). Groups and users are managed on the default instance (where I also manage all the user/group permissions), where I also created the pivot table (`group_item` in this simplified case).

```php
class Group extends Model
{
    // default connection

    public function addItem($item): void
    {
        $this->items()->attach($item);
    }

    public function items(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class);
    }
}

class Items extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'external';

    protected $primaryKey = 'item_id';
}
```

```php
public function test_group_items()
{
    $group = Group::factory()->create();

    $i = Item::first();

    $group->addItem($i);

    $this->assertTrue($group->items->contains($i));
}
```

In the above simple test, the "default" implementation has a DB reference issue, as it looks for the pivot table on the connection/DB of the passed model:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'external_db.group_item' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `group_item` (`group_id`, `items_item_id`) values (49, 1))
```

Adjusting the belongsToMany instance does fix the issue when attaching an item to the items list, however it breaks when returning the collection

```php
public function items(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->newBelongsToMany(
        $this->newQuery(),
        $this,
        'group_item',
        'item_id',
        'group_id',
        'id',
        'item_id',
        'items'
    );
}
```

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'groups.item_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `groups`.*, `group_item`.`item_id` as `pivot_item_id`, `group_item`.`group_id` as `pivot_group_id` from `groups` inner join `group_item` on `groups`.`item_id` = `group_item`.`group_id` where `group_item`.`item_id` = 74)
```

(`groups.item_id` should be `groups.id` here)

Even if the above worked, and the correct item IDs were defined from the pivot table, I wonder how could the code handle JOINs and fetching and instantiating records from the other database when calling the relation method (`$group->items()` in this case).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42584166/4530144) does solve my problem (not sure why initially it did not), and (magically) the relationship works just passing the database name!

```php
public function items(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Item::class,
        "{$this->getConnection()->getDatabaseName()}.group_item",
        null,
        'item_id'
    );
}
```